# Differentiability of partial function function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, banach-spaces, frechet-derivative

Let $E,F$ be Banach spaces. If $f\colon [0,1]\times E\to F$ is continuously differentiable, can we say something about the differentiability of
$$g\colon E\to C^1([0,1],F),\quad y\mapsto f(\cdot,y)?$$
Is $(\partial g(y)h)(t) = \partial_2f(t,y)h$ for $h\in E$?

I am a bit confused. Can someone clear this situation up? Thanks a lot.

Comment: At first sight, it appears that we can say nothing in general. The derivative of $g$ would be given, among others, by the **second-order** derivative: first in $[0,1]$, then in $E$.

Comment: Hi again @user539887! Thanks for the comment. I think I was able to answer the question positively using the theory of superposition operators...

Answer (score 0):

The question can be answered positively.

Consider the superposition operator $f^\sharp$ induced by $f$: 
$$f^\sharp\colon E^{[0,1]}\to F^{[0,1]},\quad u\mapsto f(\cdot,u(\cdot)).$$

Because $f$ is continuously differentiable it is $f^\sharp\in C^1(C([0,1],E),C([0,1],F))$ and
$$\left(\partial f^{\sharp}(u)v\right)(t) = \partial_2f(t,u(t))v(t),\quad t\in[0,1],\quad u,v\in C([0,1],E),$$
as is shown in e.g. “Analysis II” by H.Amman & J. Escher.

The answer follows from identifying $E = C_{\operatorname{const}}([0,1],E)$ and noting that 
$[y\mapsto f(\cdot,y)] = f^{\sharp}|_{C_{\operatorname{const}}([0,1],E)}.$

Comment: Notice that you have obtained only that $g \in C^1(E, C([0,1],F))$, not in $C^1(E, C^1([0,1],F))$.

Comment: @user539887 Whoops... Anyway, that's what I needed! If I want the first derivative to be bounded, too, I usually use the letters $BC^1$. Sorry, I should have clarified!

Comment: I don't know if it's appropriate to edit the question, or just leave this as it is without accepting my answer?

Comment: I am too "young" a user. Perhaps you should ask the moderator.